# php preg_replace relative to absolute in url css

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to find a regex to convert relative url in css code 'url()'. So far this is what I have:

```
$domain = "http://example.com/";
$html = "url(1.css), url(' 1.css'), url( \"1.css\")";

$rep['/url(\s*)\((\s*)"(\s*)(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/i'] = 'url("'.$domain;
$rep["/url(\s*)\((\s*)'(\s*)(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/i"] = "url('".$domain;

$html = preg_replace(
    array_keys($rep),
    array_values($rep),
    $html
);
echo $html;
```

**Current Output:**

```
url(1.css), url('http://example.com/1.css'), url("http://example.com/1.css")
```

**Desired Output:**

```
url(http://example.com/1.css), url('http://example.com/1.css'), url("http://example.com/1.css")
```

Comment: you can save only one entry in replace array `$rep['/url(\s*)\((\s*)["\']?(\s*)(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/i'] = 'url("'.$domain;`

Comment: @spash58, this will give url("http://example.com/1.css), url("http://example.com/1.css'), url("http://example.com/1.css"). Notice that " appear in all cases.

Comment: exclusively for fun :) - with one expression  https://eval.in/777666

Comment: @splash58, You did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting this? Hope it will work fine.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/777655)

**Regex:** `/url[\s]*\([\s]*(?!'|\")(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)`

Here this regex will match `url (` and after that there will be no `"` or `'`.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$domain = "http://example.com/";
$html = "url(1.css), url(' 1.css'), url( \"1.css\")";
$rep['/url[\s]*\([\s]*"[\s]*(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/i'] = 'url("'.$domain;
$rep["/url[\s]*\([\s]*'[\s]*(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/i"] = "url('".$domain;
$rep["/url[\s]*\([\s]*(?!'|\")(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/i"] = "url(".$domain;

$html = preg_replace(
    array_keys($rep),
    array_values($rep),
    $html
);
echo $html;
```